# Phabricator : Differential : Is it possible to create a review without git/svn etc using custom changeset

Tags: phabricator

Is it possible to create a review without using svn/git
Looking to leverage the approval flow without having to create a repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A differential revision is created from a diff.   You will need to have a diff submitted first from which you can create a revision for review.

It is possible to sumit a raw diff by calling `arc diff --raw` and piping the diff to it.

One example `git diff | arc diff --raw` will create a diff in phabricator that you can then create a revision from.

So - If you aren't using `git` you need a way to send in the code diff to `arc diff --raw`